# Image Segmentation and Masking

Tags: python, image-segmentation, masking

Need assistance with the simple task. I’m playing around with the [LISC dataset](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ehrezatofighi/Data/Leukocyte%20Data.htm) that contains hematological images taken from peripheral blood and segmentation masks of manual ground truth for these graphical samples. The task is the following:

1. Segment isolated leukocytes by removing/cropping irrelevant background elements using the segmentation masks given in the dataset. Try this on one sample only.
2. Once accomplished, go through the whole folder, and segment/crop the rest of the samples.

Results should be like this (these were obtained via a combination of Mask R-CNN, GrabCut, and OpenCV — but not suitable for the current project I’m working on):

[image: Original Image]
[image: Mask & Segmented Image]

Here is the code that I’ve got so far (from jupyter notebook):

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_images
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import cv2

original = imread(r'D:\mask\1_original.bmp')
plt.imshow(original)
```

[image]

```
segmented = imread(r'D:\mask\1_mask.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, mask = cv2.threshold(segmented, thresh=180, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

plt.imshow(segmented)
```

[image]

I don't know why the image changed its colors since the original mask looks like this (just black and gray):

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using for the final result, but colors are distorted and different from the original once the mask is applied, and this is what I'm trying to fix now but to no avail:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import cv2

img_org = cv2.imread(r'D:\mask\1_original.bmp')
img_mask = cv2.imread(r'D:\mask\1_mask.bmp')

##Resizing images
img_org = cv2.resize(img_org, (400,400),  interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
img_mask = cv2.resize(img_mask, (400,400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

for h in range(len(img_mask)):
    for w in range(len(img_mask)):
        if img_mask[h][w][0] == 0:
            for i in range(3):
                img_org[h][w][i] = 0
        else:
            continue
                      
plt.imshow(img_org)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear, so modify your question title and text to emphasize this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your real question is "why is the image shown in yellow and dark blue rather than black and grey or black and white? This has to do with the colormap used by matplotlib, which by default is "viridis" (blue to green to yellow). Sounds like you want "binary". See a full list of colormaps here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html 

In any case, specify colormap as : 
`plt.imshow(segmented, cmap=plt.get_cmap("binary"))`

Comment: Hey @DerekG, thanks for stepping in! Yeah, specifying the colormap worked and I've fixed the issue with the yellow color. Thanks.

Comment: @DerekG, the main snag here is the color of the final image (the last one in the post), the basophil color is different from the original image (at the top of the post) after applying the mask. Can you please inspect the last code snippet and suggest any tweaks that could fix this?

Comment: Cool cool, I added the info in an answer below. If this gives you what you need I recommend accepting the answer and closing the question as I suspect the information in this question is repeated elsewhere on SE. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in colors is the result of the specified heatmap (viridis instead of binary) as noted above in comments.

The output image has different coloration than the input image because OpenCV uses BGR rather than RGB for colors, so it's likely your red and blue channels are swapped. If you read an image with OpenCV and plot with Matplotlib or vice versa. There are two easy solutions:

1.) Both read and plot images with OpenCV. You can replace `plt.imshow(im_orig)` with:

```
cv2.imshow("window name", im_orig)
cv2.waitKey(0) # waits until a key is pressed before continuing
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

2.) Swap the R and B channels before plotting with `plt.imshow()`:

```
im_orig = cv2.cvtColor(im_orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(im_orig)
```